# elasticsearch_dsl and python -Query Previous Days Index Only - Performance vs _all

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm writing some code to query data in Elasticsearch. We have huge amounts of data so I am using a scan feature and searching a specific index. We index elasticsearch by the day, so for example `today = index_2019_04_15` and `yesterday = index_2019_04_14`. Is there a way I can query only the previous days index?

Second, in terms of doing _all and then limiting the query to say `2019-04-14`, will I see a big performance hit? If not, then I can just do a previous day query.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search
from elasticsearch_dsl import connections

class get_data:

    def __init__(self, host, query):
        self.host = host
        self.query = query

    def pull_es_data(self):
        connections.create_connection(alias='client',hosts=self.host,timeout=60)

        s = Search(using='client', index="data-2019-04-15") \
        .query("match", clientid=r"AB1234-12345")

        response = s.scan()

        return response

test = get_data("localhost","test")

x = test.pull_es_data()

results_df = pd.DataFrame(([item.clientid,item.clientlocation] for item in x),\
                          columns=['clientid','clientlocation'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to take care of this using Index in Elasticsearch-dsl

```
def get_index_list(self):

    i = Index("*").get_alias("client")

    return i
```